# Router navigate redirect after authentication does not render component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to redirect to my home component after authentication. The redirection is successful, but the home component does not render. If I move this.router.navigate outside the subscribe block, it will render properly.

```
export class LoginComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private router: Router,
                private authService: AuthenticationService) {

        this.authService.authenticationStream().subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In chrome dev tools, I can see all of the home component's template except for a ngFor block:

```
<md-grid-tile *ngFor="let tile of CONFIG.tiles">
    {{ tile }}
</md-grid-tile>
```

I can verify CONFIG.tiles is populated.

Why would the ngFor block not be rendered after navigation, specfically from a navigate call inside of an Observable subscription?

EDIT: Adding AuthenticationService code:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(private http: HttpService,
              private store: Store<AppStore>) {
    }

    authenticate(): void {
        let uri = 'http://uri.com'
        this.http.post(uri).subscribe(() => {
            // Dispatch event to ngrx store if user is successfully authenticated
            this.store.dispatch({type: AUTHENTICATED});
        });
    }

    authenticationStream(): Observable<boolean> {
        // Emits events from dispatch calls
        return <Observable<boolean>> this.store.select(AUTHENTICATION);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `authService`authenticationStream`?

Comment: `authService.authenticationStream()` returns an Observable stream of boolean values indicating authentication status

Comment: Please add the code that shows it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `authenticationStream` emits events outside Angulars zone which breaks change detection and would lead to the behavior you described.

You can use `zone.run()` to force execution back into Angulars zone:

```
export class LoginComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private router: Router,
                private authService: AuthenticationService
                zone: NgZone) {

        this.authService.authenticationStream().subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
            if (isAuthenticated) {
                zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/home']));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it might be worth investigating why that happens and it might be better to apply `zone.run()` where the code starts to run outside the zone but for that I would need to see more code (`authService.authenticationStream` and where events are emitted using it).

Comment: Hey Gunter, what does zone.run do? Create a new scope?

Comment: Angular2 runs code inside a zone. A zone is a scope where (most) async APIs (`addEventHandler`, `removeEventHandler`, `setTimeout`, ...) are patched so Angular2 gets notified when some event happened. Angular2 runs change detection every time an event happened and all event handlers are done. If code runs outside Angulars zone, change detection doesn't happen, which leads to the behavior you describe. `zone.run()` makes a thread of execution (that might be outside Angulars zone) continue inside it's zone.
Code running outside Angulars zone happens when some unpatched async API is used.

Comment: I don't know `store` or what causes it to run outside Angulars zone. I don't have a better solution than my answer above even after seeing more code.

Comment: I was having a similar issue and trying to wrap the call in NgZone, but seeing how you wrapped only the subscription callback inside of zone.run did the trick. Thanks a million times !